# R: Remover colunas de um dataframe

Tags: r, data.frame

Como posso remover colunas de um `dataframe` sem ser da seguinte forma?

```
> df
  x y z
1 1 6 A
2 1 5 B
3 2 4 C
4 2 3 D
5 3 2 E
6 3 1 F
> df <- data.frame(df[,1:2])
> df
  x y
1 1 6
2 1 5
3 2 4
4 2 3
5 3 2
6 3 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais prática é a seguinte:  `df$z <- NULL`.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer assim também:

```
df[, -3]
```

Indices negativos excluem colunas no `R`.

Se quiser excluir mais de uma coluna, faça assim:

```
df[,-c(1,3)]
```

O problema dessa forma é que se sobrar apenas uma coluna ela é automaticamente transformada em um vetor. Se não quiser esse comportamento  use o argumento `drop = F`.

```
df[,-c(1,3), drop = F]
```

Outra forma é usando o pacote `dplyr` e a função `select`:

```
df %>% select(-z)
```

Ou

```
df %>% select(-3)
```

---

Muitas vezes você quer excluir uma coluna sem saber o nome dela previamente. Por exemplo o nome dela está salvo em uma variável.

Neste caso você pode fazer assim:

```
nome_col <- "z"
df[[nome_col]] <- NULL
```

Se quiser excluir diversas colunas dessa forma, pode fazer assim:

```
nomes_col <- c("z", "x")
df[ , -which(names(df) %in% nomes_col), drop = F]
```

Neste caso, uso o argumento `drop = F` para que o `data.frame` não vire vetor.

Answer (score 1):

Há ainda outra forma, um pouco mais obscura:

```
df[setdiff(names(df), "z")]
```